# How to transfer a drawing on Xcode 8 between view controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, drawing, core-graphics

I'm trying to make this app where I draw on one view controller and then I go to a different view controller and have the same drawing there too. I have been looking everywhere and I haven't found anything about transferring drawing between view controllers. I am a high school and am very much a beginner into using any coding, especially with Xcode 8 and Swift 3. I would would appreciate any tips you can give. Thanks! :)

Update: So I am drawing on an UIimage on one view controller and trying to get that same drawing onto another view controller as just for show, it doesn't need to be edited after it is transferred.

This is all the code I have to draw on the UIimage

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewPass: UIImageView!

var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
var swiped = false
var red:CGFloat = 0.0
var green:CGFloat = 0.0
var blue:CGFloat = 0.0

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    swiped = false

    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
    }
}

func drawlines(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    drawOnIMageFeet.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(5)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)

    context?.strokePath()

    drawOnIMageFeet.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    swiped = true

    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        drawlines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if !swiped {
        drawlines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }
}

    @IBAction func pickColor(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        (red,green,blue) = (1,0,0)
    } else if sender.tag == 1 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0,1,0)
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0,0,1)
    } else if sender.tag == 3 {
        (red,green,blue) = (1,0,1)
    } else if sender.tag == 4 {
        (red,green,blue) = (1,1,0)
    } else if sender.tag == 5 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0,1,1)
    } else if sender.tag == 6 {
        (red,green,blue) = (0,0,0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: You want to store it into property I would say UIImage, but I don't know how is the drawing made. Then you should send it as parameter into new ViewController

Comment: Firstly please show the code you have tried as has been said.  How you do this will depend on what you want to do with the drawing information and how you are drawing it.  If you just want to have it as an image to display after then you can do as has been suggested and convert it to a UIImage however if you want to be able to manipulate it then you need to store the information (data points) needed to create the image.

Comment: @TobySpeight I added the code of all I have, if you could reply asap, that would be amazing

Comment: @ZuzanaPaulis what do you mean by sending it as a parameter?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I can't figure out a way to convert the drawing to a UIimage. I won't need to manipulate it, I just want to display it on a different view controller

Comment: As a start you should store your list of points into an array and then that array can be passed around and used to draw the image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring data to another view controller when using segues is relatively simple. When a transition is about to happen, the `prepare(for:sender:)` function is called on the current view controller (check out the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare)).

Assuming `drawOnIMageFeet` is a property of your current view controller, the function would probably look something like this for you:

```
func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?)
{
    // vc will be the view controller that will be displayed after the transition
    if let vc = segue.destination as? MyNextViewController
    {
        // do your transferring of data/setup here
        vc.imageToDraw = drawOnIMageFeet

        // other setup
    }
}
```

With multiple segues coming from a single view controller, I usually just determine what to do based on which view controller class is the destination. However, if you have multiple different segues going from one view controller into another, you can use the `identifier` property of the `UIStoryboardSegue` class to further discriminate between segues.

Comment: The problem is that the drawing that I draw on the current view controller/drawOnImageFeet won't show up in the second view controller

Comment: Maybe I'm not being as clear as I thought. Drawing happens in views, which contain other subviews in what's called the view hierarchy. Each view controller has its own hierarchy of views that are entirely separate from those of other view controllers, so what you draw in the view of the first view controller needs to be transferred to the second view controller so it can draw it in its own view. The transfer is done via the function I explained above. Once the second view controller has the image of what was drawn, it still needs to display the image in its view (show it in a `UIImageView`).